# Importing a module in a React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm new to the ES6 module system so this may sound silly.

In the [React Native Starter App](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit) that uses NativeBase, can anyone explain how [`native-starter-kit/js/components/home/index.js`](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit/blob/master/js/components/home/index.js) can do

```
import myTheme from '../../themes/base-theme`;
```

when the file it is importing from,  [`native-starter-kit/js/themes/base-theme.js`](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit/blob/master/js/themes/base-theme.js) did not have any code that `export default` the variable `myTheme`?

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd file you are refering to is an entire export default.
On line 5 :

```
export default {

// Badge
badgeBg: '#ED1727',
badgeColor: '#fff',

...

}
```

So when they do `import myTheme from '../../themes/base-theme;` the `myTheme` is the variable name they chose for the imported module. In this case, the transpiler is going to look for the `default` export.

If they would have done `import { myTheme } from '../../themes/base-theme;` then there would have been an issue since it is not explicitly named in the export. Doing this is not refering to the `default` export but rather the one explicitly called `myTheme`

I am not sure I made sense, you may want to give https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/import a read

Answer (score 2):

Exporting without **default** means it's a **named export**.

You can have multiple named exports in a single file.

Example 1:

`export class Theme {}`

Here you have to import this export using its exact name.

To use this component in other file you should do this,

`import { Theme } from '../../themes/base-theme'`

Example 2:

If you export as the **default** export as,

`export default class Theme {}`

Then in another file you import the default export without using the { }, like this,

`import Theme from '../../themes/base-theme'`

There can only be one default export per file.

Although its React's convention to export one component from a file, and to export it is as the default export.

You're free to rename the default export as you import it.

`import myTheme from '../../themes/base-theme'`